# Can i query a list of items in a wordpress form without using databases

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a form in my wordpress site that will have also a dropdown list of items (like a few hundreds) and based on the item chosen and other options the form will deliver a result.I’m not a software engineer but i have some experice with wordpress but not using databases. Is there a way to avoid using databases in this scenario?

Comment: Nothing you've described directly requires a database. Where were you thinking it would be needed?

Comment: First, a dropdown list of hundreds of items can just be in HTML, no PHP and thus no database is required, although for management reasons it might be easier to store them in a PHP array or a database. Second, when someone selects something and something happens, that’s where programmers come in. Whether a database is needed is up to the programmer. Third, if WordPress is aware that this page exists, a database _will_ be involved, no matter what. It might not be for the specific logic, but there will be many queries just to do normal “WordPress stuff”.

Comment: I was thinking that the list mit have a database in the backend in order to run properly, but i might have a simple solutions if i will use tablepress plugin to store the data and use a shorcode to add it to the list.